# Trying to terminate a char array and print afterwards

Tags: c, arrays, char

I'm making a char array binary representations of a number. I want to terminate the end of the string with '\0'. It prints the array find aside from the intended garbage value.

However when I try to terminate the array, specifically the index of the garbage value, it won't print out my string.

```
int main(void)
{
    char s[8] = {0};
    printing_binary(s, 8, 2);

}

void printing_binary(char *s, int length,  unsigned n){

    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
        if(1 & (n >> i)){
            s[i] = '1';
        }
        else{
            s[i] = '0';
        }
    }
    //Trying to terminate my string
    //s[length] = '\0';
    printf(s);
}
```

This code will print out something like `01000000}`.

However if I uncomment out `s[length] = '\0'`, it prints nothing/the program stops executing. I've tried printing out "Hello world" after everything.

Comment: use s[length-1] = '\0';

Comment: `s[length]` is outside the array bounds... Even reading it is undefined behavior. The last element is `s[length-1]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you define your result array as `char s[8]`, then you must not write anything at position `8` like in `s[length] = 0x0` with `length==8`, because this exceeds the array length. Try:

```
char s[9] = {0};
printing_binary(s, (9-1), 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an 8 bit length which you fill up with the values. For example the value 2 is `00000010` Since you have filled up your string array, you have no room for the ending character. **If you define the array size as length+1, then it will work**.

```
int main(void)
{
    char s[9] = {0}; // Note size is length+1
    printing_binary(s, 8, 2);

}

void printing_binary(char *s, int length,  unsigned n){

    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
        if(1 & (n >> i)){
            s[i] = '1';
        }
        else{
            s[i] = '0';
        }
    }
    //Trying to terminate my string
    s[length] = '\0'; // s must be an array of size greater than length
    printf(s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to add a null terminator, you just have t modify the printf slightly.

```
int main(void)
{
    char s[8] = {0};
    printing_binary(s, 8, 2);

}

void printing_binary(char *s, int length,  unsigned n){

    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
        if(1 & (n >> i)){
            s[i] = '1';
        }
        else{
            s[i] = '0';
        }
    }
    //Trying to terminate my string
    //s[length] = '\0';
    printf("%.*s", length, s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to declare `i` outside the loop. This can be useful if for some reason your logic breaks out of the loop before reaching `length`

```
int i;
for ( i=0; i < length; i++ ) {
   ...
}
s[i] = '\0';
```